# Citrix XenDesktop error 2314: .ica file has duplicate lines in WFClient section

Tags: virtualization, xendesktop, citrix

On one laptop, when going to the web interface for launching a XenDesktop session over the intranet, the XenDesktop window opens and then an error message shows up:

> Error number 2314
>   The Citrix online plug-in received a corrupt ICA File. ICA File section WFClient contains duplicate keys named (d)

Citrix Online Plugin version is 12.1.

On clicking the desired XenDesktop link on that web interface, four .ica files are deposited in C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Temp. One of these files indeed has duplicate entries under WFClient "d=On".

Apparently, beginning with client version 10, duplicate entries in the .ica files results in a connection failure as Citrix considers this a security risk.

I am having difficulty finding out what the "d" option means under WFClient. Does anybody know what this stands for and where duplicate entries may have been introduced?

When using a different computer, there are no "d" entries under WFClient in any of the four .ica files dropped during the connection.

Comment: Hey, I got a badge for being ignored. Sweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reimaging this particular computer for a different issue. The problem has not reoccured. Therefore I was unable to determine what caused the initial duplicate entries and the resulting problems.